# Control manipulator mechanical arm by infrared

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, control, remote-control

I want to make an infrared control circuit (remote) connected to the Manipulator Mechanical Arm. I found this circuit, but the outlet is 230 volts, and I do not think that the arm will handle this high voltage. How do we solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: That is a bizarre way to control a relay, but probably doable with stuff the average hobbyist had laying around in...1995.  We need more information about the arm you're trying to control. What are the normal control signals?  How many are there?

Comment: Add a 1 kohm resistor in the base path of T1 to not destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

You have no problem to solve.

The relay contacts do not generate 230V, so if you do not send 230V into relay then it does not come out to your device either.

The relay can be used for anything, as long as current and voltage are within safe limits of your relay.

So use the relay between your supply and your load.